# Single SMB transfer doesn't saturate bandwidth, concurrent to same location does. Why?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, samba, file-sharing

> **From** \\Win7\C\Src\File1.bin **To** \\XP\C\Dest
>
> **From** \\Win7\C\Src\File2.bin **To** \\XP\C\Dest

The connection between the machines is 100Mbit Ethernet. When I copy *File1.bin* from the Win7 machine to XP, the transfer speed hovers around 7MB/s. If I concurrently start a second transfer (*File2.bin*) then the total transfer speed averages 10MB/s, which is to be expected in this scenario.

Why is a single file transfer not able to utilize the full available bandwidth? Clearly the hardware (HDD, switch, etc.) is not the limiting factor since starting 2 simultaneous transfers from/to the same share does maximize throughput.

Comment: Do you happen to have "QoS Packet Scheduler" enabled under the network connection? Try disabling it [like so](http://i.imgur.com/DhWvGVn.png).

Answer (score 0):

Turning off QoS on both machines boosted the speed of a single transfer to 9MB/s. Upgrading the XP machine to Win7 resulted in a 11MB/s transfer speed regardless of QoS setting. Ergo: SMBv2 on both clients fixed the problem.

Comment: PS: can't accept this as answer because of deleted, unregistered account ;)

Comment: Unlike XP, Windows 7 has HomeGroup and 128-bit encryption enabled by default: http://windowssecrets.com/top-story/simple-change-in-settings-pumps-up-win7-networks/